# $1+2+3+4+5+..... = -\frac{1}{12}$. Is there any intuition for this?

Tags: number-theory, summation

I was looking into a Numberphile video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww). The guy says he was unable to find an intuition. Does there exist one? Is the premise, $1-1+1-1+...=\frac{1}{2}$, reasonable mathematically?

Comment: This has been asked here before.

Comment: All I can say is that your equation is false, at least to **my interpretation** of your symbols. Now if you explicitly defined your symbols, then you'd have your answer.

Comment: All you need to know is that it is an abused and misused result of the zeta function. Those people on numberphile do not know what they are on about.

Comment: @Alizter Or perhaps worse, they know and made the video nevertheless.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahhh youu!!

Comment: @Alizter Not really. You just need to get out of Cauchy's axioms. Free. Your. Mind. That is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intuition is that $\zeta(s) \equiv \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ evaluates to $1+2+3+\cdots$ when $s=-1$.

However, the fact of the matter is that this definition of the zeta function holds for complex $s$ such that $\textrm{Re}(s) > 1$, so it is not generally true for $s=-1$.

Now, it is possible through a process known as *analytic continuation* to "extend" the zeta function to $s=-1$, however when doing so, the equivalence between $\zeta(-1)$ and $1+2+3+\cdots$ breaks down.

This is because infinite series are defined as the limits of their partial sums. So $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k$ diverges, and while you can interpret it some other ways, if you want to speak the language of infinite sums, you have to accept the partial sum limit definition.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not. the sum $1 - 1 + 1 - ...$ does not converge, it has no meaning to say that since you can stop at zero or at $1$, then it equals $\frac{1}{2}$

Sometimes this stuff can have meaning but you have to define precisely what you mean by "sum", or "equal", because with stuff that goes to infinity there are a lot of problems :-D

An example I can think of is $$1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

This series converges (so that "equal" has meaning) only if $|x| < 1$. 
In some areas of math people extended the above definition so that it make sense for every x, also, say, $x=3$. But it's a definition and you have to be really cautios with that.

But of course people will start telling that it is "proven" that $$1 + 3 + 9 + 27 + ... = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think this should have been included for the premise in the video: 
Let $x:=1-1+1-1+1-\dots$, then we have
$$x=1-(1-1+1-1+\dots)=1-x$$
so $2x=1,\ \ x=1/2$.